# Why isn't this android animation doing anything?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-xml, objectanimator

I'm trying to use the newer style of Android property animators (rather than the older view animations) to create an animation to shake a view horizontally.

I've written the following XML animator in `/res/animator/shake.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="translationX"
    android:duration="100"
    android:valueFrom="0f"
    android:valueTo="20f"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="7"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

I have created the following Kotlin extension method to play the animation on any view:

```
fun View.shake() {
    AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.shake).apply {
        setTarget(this)
        start()
    }
}
```

When I call the animation however, nothing happens, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put `setTarget(this)` and `start()` in `apply{}`

Replace your code with this:

```
fun View.shake() {
    val al = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.shake)
    al.setTarget(this)
    al.start()
}
```

Or you can do:

```
AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.shake).apply {
        setTarget(this@shake)
        start()
    }
```

Earlier `this` was referring to `AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator` and not the `View`, so just replace it with `this@shake` to refer it to the `view` on which you are applying the animation.

Comment: This is correct, but I can't mark it as accepted unless you explain why what I did was wrong.